# How to import and use onItemClickListener for TwoWayView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have successfully used the TwoWayView to implement a horizontal list for my project. But now I am trying to handle the onItemClick events. So i tried adding the twowayview:core so i can use those functions. But when i write in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:layouts:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
```

I get an error saying:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> Error: more than one library with package name 'org.lucasr.twowayview'
>   You can temporarily disable this error with
>   android.enforceUniquePackageName=false However, this is temporary and
>   will be enforced in 1.0

Can someone please help me on how to import in my project the core functions so I can use the onItemClickListeners?

GitHub repo that I used to import TwoWayView in my project:
https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

Answer (score 0):

You're installing two different versions of TwoWayView: 0.1.4 and 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Remove one of them from your Gradle.